# Dice with same letter on each side

Tags: dice, boggle

I would like to surprise somebody by spelling out a phrase in Boggle. When we start playing, they will instantly recognize the phrase.

When we have play in the past, the other person is virtually always the one to mix up the letters right before starting. If we didn't need to shake up the letters, it would be easy—just pre-spell the word. But I need to have each particular dice have the same letter on each of its sides (different dice will have different letters) so that no matter how they are shaken up, they will always spell what I want.

1. Are there any dice (Boggle size) that have the same letter on each side?
2. If not, what would be the best way to modify existing Boggle dice to produce this result?
3. Are there any other ways to go about this that wouldn't cause suspicion?

Comment: Even if you can get the same letter on each side how will you be certain they always land in same space to spell out the phrase?  When they are shaken the dice don't just change side they will also change space.

Comment: If this is a proposal, it's an awesome idea. There's all sorts of websites where you could get custom dice made I'm sure.

Comment: @StartPlayer, yes, this is a great point. I may have to try to shake them up myself, but do so in a particular way to minimize the chance that they change position. I would probably want to practice this beforehand to test if it is feasible.

Comment: ...and hope that the fact that I shake them up doesn't draw suspicion.

Comment: You don't need the letters to line up in horizontal words. In fact, you don't want them to, It's Boggle. You just need the right letters in a contiguous chain. Your target will not recognize the phrase instantly, but become aware of the phrase as she attempts to find words. If you simplify the phrase sufficiently, you can increase the letter frequency to increase the likelihood of the phrase showing up the first round. "Will you marry me?" could be shortened to "marry me? and you'd double the letter frequency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What ended up happening was as follows. I first pre-arranged the letters well ahead of time by myself. Luckily, the other person needed to go into another room for some reason. I used this opportunity to suggest that we play Boggle, which was agreed to. I then quickly got the game ready. When the other person returned, I claimed that I had already shaken it up. It worked out nicely.

Because they left the room, I didn't have to deal with the problems I mentioned, such as suggesting that I be the one to shake the letters up and then trying to fake doing so, but in a convincing manner.

Comment: So, can we congratulate you?

Comment: Yes, I accomplished what I set out to do.